# Ruby: Modify a Range

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add a method to the `Range` class. The goal is to check if an integer is is included in the range and to include it if it isn't. It would be useful to store in a `Range` some minimum and maximum values.

So I was thinking of the following:

```
class Range   
  def include!(n)
    if n < self.begin
      self = n..self.end
    elsif n > self.end
      self = self.begin..n
    end   
  end 
end

r = Range.new(500, 500)
100.times do
  r.include!(rand(1000))
end
```

But I get a `Can't change the value of self` error.

Would this be the only solution:

```
class Range
  def include(n)
    if n < self.begin
      n..self.end
    elsif n > self.end
      self.begin..n
    else
      self
    end
  end
end

r = Range.new(500, 500)
100.times do
  r = r.include(rand(1000))
end
```

Comment: Ranges are immutable, you can't change them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranges themselves are immutable, you can't change their properties after they are created. However, it's still possible to achieve what you want by creating new ranges instead of modifying existing ones, as you discovered. I'd probably do it like this:

```
module RangeAdder
  def +(value)
    return self if value.nil?
    return self + value.min + value.max if value.is_a? Range
    return value.reduce(self, :+) if value.is_a? Enumerable

    new_begin       = [self.begin, value].min
    new_end         = [self.end, value].max
    new_exclude_end = value > self.end ? false : self.exclude_end?
    Range.new(new_begin, new_end, new_exclude_end)
  end
end

class Range
  include RangeAdder
end
```

Then:

```
r = 500..500
r += Array.new(100) { rand(1000) }
#=> 15..982
```

Or if all you really want to do is get the minimum and maximum values from an array, you can do that with:

```
a = Array.new(100) { rand(1000) }
r = Range.new(*a.minmax)
#=> 11..996
```

Comment: Why use a module and not simply `class Range; def +(value)` ?

Comment: @Victor More flexibility (you could subclass Range and include the module in that instead) and better debug output and documentation (it's easier to determine where the + method came from). Plus I'm always just kinda hesitant to monkey patch core classes like that.